# Erro ao retornar menor valor

Tags: c, algoritmo

Eu estou tentando retornar o menor valor usando o `va_args`, que suporta vários argumentos, mas ele sempre retorna o mesmo número: -13227;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int minimo(int args, ...) 
{
    int elemento, min;

    va_list valist;
    va_start(valist, args);

    min = INT_MAX;
    for(int i=0; i<args; i++)
    {
        elemento = va_arg(valist, int);
        if(elemento < min)
            min = elemento;
    }

    va_end(valist);

     return min;
}

int main() 
{           
    int num = minimo(8, 5, 3, 7, 12, 6);
    printf("%d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

E se altera a variável `min` de *int* para *unsigned int*, retorna sempre 0.
https://ideone.com/9TNKLp

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Aqui diz que `min` é o maior valor possível:

```
min = INT_MAX;
```

Então pergunta

```
if (min < elemento)
```

Se `min` é o maior valor possível jamais ele será o mínimo, nunca entrará neste `if`.

Se fizer o contrário aí funciona:

```
if (elemento < min)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/Comparison.c).

Além disto o primeiro argumento passado na função deve ser a quantidade de elementos que terá a seguir, usou 8 quando na verdade só tem 5, isto pega sujeira de memória e estraga a comparação.

Comment: Eu havia colocado: if (elemento < min),antes, mas postei errado,mas não retorna a entrada correta.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é essa linha aqui:

```
if(min < elemento)
```

Acredito que o sinal está trocado. O bloco desse `if` somente é executado se `min` for **menor** que o elemento comparado, mas `min` jamais será menor que qualquer outra coisa já que, por definição, seu valor inicial é o maior valor possível.

Answer (score 0):

2 coisas.

Uma é que o sinal estava trocado no if, já dita pelos colegas, a outra é que você forneceu 5 números, mas disse que tinha 8, então o seu laço for tenta acessar parâmetros que não existem.

Chame sua função assim que não terá problemas:

```
minimo(5, 5, 3, 7, 12, 6);
```

Comment: Parece que agora funcionou.

Comment: então só marcar como resposta ;)